# Referencing web api in virtual directory with jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api, umbraco

My collegues and I are working on a web API that we are communicating with using knockoutjs (via Umbraco CMS). To avoid running into cross site scripting security built into browsers, we have the api located in a virtual directory in our website directory.

If we place a "stupid" html file in the directory, we can "talk" to the api with no problems. If we, on the other hand, try to reference the api in the virtual directory from umbraco it isnt found.

I looked around for various solutions, but most, if not all, are if you are using MVC3 which solutions doesnt really help.

Here is a bit of the javascript that tries to contact the API:

```
function subscribe() {
  if($("#siteForm").valid()=== true){
    alert("add subscriptiooncalled");
    var mySubscription = ko.toJS(ViewModel);
    var json = JSON.stringify(mySubscription);
    alert(json);
    $.ajax({
        url: API_URL,
        cache: false,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: json,  
        success: function (data) {
            alert("data is pushed");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("ERROR STATUS: " + error.status + "  STATUS TEXT: " + error.statusText);
        }

    });
  }else{

  }
}
```

Doing this doesnt work either:

```
var root = location.protocol + "//" + location.host;
var API_URL = root + "/api/Subscriptions/";
```

Note the alerts are for testing purposes. Anyway, the url in the code obviously dont work, and inserting the full url doesnt work either (http:// etc. etc).

Any suggestions? Using Umbraco 4.7.2 if it helps.

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**
Well this is stupid. Maybe its the culmination of several different solutions, maybe its not, but it all came down to the submit button.
Yup. By changing the buttons type form "submit" to "button" everything worked.
Oh god this was silly.

Comment: location.host only resolves your top domain and will not have the virtual directory name in it. The url should be something like http://www.application.com/virtualdirectory/api/Subscriptions/. You can test this easily by browsing to the url. Once you have the correct url i would try to use it like that in your javascript function. If that succeeds look how you can make it installation independent.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the path to your API to the "umbracoReservedPaths" appSetting in the site's web.config. That will tell umbraco to exclude that path from processing. Jonas Ericksson gives a good example of how to do this in a [blog post](http://joeriks.com/2011/03/03/an-ordinary-webmatrix-app-in-an-umbraco-subfolder/) he wrote.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that WebApi routes are being overriden by Umbraco.

In order to have WebApi and Umbraco side by side, (in Umbraco 4.11) you have to implement IApplicationEventHandler, but I'm afraid in 4.7 this shouldn't work and you have to use something different (inherit from ApplicationBase if memory serves). The code needed for Umbraco 4.11+ would look somewhat like this:

```
public class WebApiStartupHandler : IApplicationEventHandler
{
    public void OnApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplication httpApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); // register web api routes
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);            // register mvc routes
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters); // register global filters
    }
}
```

This would allow your webapi project to run side by side with your umbraco website and you wouldn't have to use a virtual directory.

Adding "~/api" (or whatever you like to use as your api root) to umbracoReservedUrls and umbracoReservedPaths in the appConfig section of your web.config file may also solve your problem, especially if running the api in a virtual directory is a requirement.